# Trying to show to chosen day as text after the DatePicker

Tags: android, date, time, jodatime

```
  //When user clicks "other".
    public void setDate(View view) {
        DateTime dateTime=new DateTime();


        new DatePickerDialog(CreateEventActivity.this, listener, dateTime.getYear(), dateTime.getMonthOfYear(), dateTime.getDayOfWeek()).show();
    }

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            DateTime eventDate = new DateTime();
            eventDate.withYear(year);
            eventDate.withMonthOfYear(monthOfYear + 1);
            eventDate.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth);

            time = eventDate;

            Context appContext = getApplicationContext();
            Toast.makeText(appContext, dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year + "," +eventDate.dayOfWeek().getAsText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            dateTxt.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
            dayTxt.setText(eventDate.dayOfWeek().getAsText());

            otherButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#77B3FC"));
            todayButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DBDBDB"));
            tomorrowButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DBDBDB"));



        }
    };
```

I have a problem with this part: `eventDate.dayOfWeek().getAsText()`
It shows the wrong day of the week, but the date in numbers is fine.

(Just started using Joda-Time so I'm not sure about it...)

**EDIT:**
The date in numbers like: 23.7.16 is printed correctly, But I want it to show which day is it in the week, like "Monday"... I've noticed it always writes today's name. In the toast and in the text view...

**For example,** for couple of different dates it will show: 
23.6.16, Friday|
15.7.16, Friday|
30.8.17, Friday

Comment: I don't know if it may cause an error, but on create the DatePickerDialog, he expects the day of the month and not the day of the week. From Android documentation `DatePickerDialog(Context context, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth)`

Comment: I tried to change it, same result

Comment: The day is printed correctly in the Toast or is wrong in both ? What the difference is ? if it's 1 day is normal, because in the DayPicker the week start in 0

Comment: The date in numbers like: 23.7.16 is printed correctly, But I want it to show which day is it in the week, like "Monday"... I've noticed it always writes today's name.

Comment: So the date in Toast is like 23.16.16, Friday correct ? Try print the number of the day on the week instead of name, just for debug

Comment: Ok, tried to put eventDate.getDayOfWeek() in order to get the number... It crashed the app, with this error: http://prntscr.com/bhj69y

Comment: the crash is because you return is not a String, put `""+` before the mehod

Comment: Ok, I did, It didn't crash. Now it shows me always number 5.

Comment: Ah man, the others data are right because you are using the data of the DataPicker and not of the JodaTime, may have some error in your construction try `DateTime eventDate = new DateTime(year,monthOfYear+1,dayOfMonth,0,0,0);` the 0,0,0 are hours, minutes and seconds, remove the 3 lines : `eventDate.withYear(year);
            eventDate.withMonthOfYear(monthOfYear + 1);
            eventDate.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth);`

Comment: It works! Thanks!! Can I accept your answer here in the comments? And can you explain to me why this is worked and the "with" didn't?

Comment: I will put it in an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the others data are right because you are using the data of the DataPicker and not of the JodaTime, may have some error in your construction try:

```
DateTime eventDate = new DateTime(year,monthOfYear+1,dayOfMonth,0,0,0);
```

the 0,0,0 are hours, minutes and seconds, remove the 3 lines :

```
eventDate.withYear(year); 
eventDate.withMonthOfYear(monthOfYear + 1); 
eventDate.withDayOfMonth(dayOfMonth);
```